# how to determine type of file using javascript when onload?

Tags: javascript

I have certain uploaded file code as following:

```
<script>
var input_file = document.getElementById('txt_list');
input_file.onchange = function() {
           var file = this.files[0];
           var reader = new FileReader();
           reader.onload = function(ev) {
                //myProcesses
           };
           reader.readAsText(file);
        };
</script>
```

How can I add new function to determine the type of uploaded file either txt, gif, etc? and if i have to validate it, what am i supposed to do then?
Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i get file extensions with javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190852/how-can-i-get-file-extensions-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return (/[.]/.exec(filename)) ? /[^.]+$/.exec(filename) : undefined;
```

or

```
return filename.split('.').pop();
```

please refer this link for more details -[LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190852/how-can-i-get-file-extensions-with-javascript)

if u need a txt file only

save it to a variable and use a if else statement to verify it

```
var file=file.split('.').pop();


if (type=='txt'){
//do something
}else{
//do something
}
```

Comment: use this var file=file.split('.').pop(); see my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

split the filename then second part will give you file extension

```
 return file .split('.').pop();
```

so if file is **`name.txt`** this will return **`txt`**

edit-

if you only have to check the filetype

```
var filetype=file.split('.').pop();
if(filetype!="txt"){
return false;
}
```

Comment: var file = this.files[0];    return file .split('.').pop();

Comment: ok thanks. And maybe my next question, if it's not too much, what if I have to validate it? I need .txt only, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`File.type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/File.type) to determine the mime type and check it against valid mime types.