# Get extension from a file url

Tags: javascript, html

I am using file(input) to select a file. I want to retrieve the file extension(.jpeg) from a URL `C:\Users\Rajat\Pictures\pic1.jpeg`. Then after that I want to put the URL into a text box according to their format i.e audio, video and image.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i get file extensions with javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190852/how-can-i-get-file-extensions-with-javascript)

Comment: `'C:\Users\Rajat\Pictures\pic1.jpeg'.split('.').splice(-1)[0]`

Comment: 1) what are you trying to achieve exactly (I suppose putting the path in the textboxes has some kind of finality) 2) what have you tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case you better go with mimetype instead of extensions.

```
var fileInput = document.getElementById('your-file-input-id');
var fileType = fileInput.files[0].type;
console.log(fileType);//gives image/jpeg or audio/mp3
var parts = filetype.split('/');
parts[0];//image
parts[1];//jpeg
```

Answer (score 2):

Using ES2022's [`Array.at()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at) (see link for browser support), you can do it in a one liner like so:

```js
const url = "https://example.com/my-file.jpg";
const extension = url.split(".")?.at(-1);
console.log(extension);
```

Comment: This is nice :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var url='C:\Users\Rajat\Pictures\pic1.jpeg';
var parts=url.split('.');
console.log(parts[parts.length-1]);
```