# What's the purpose of the Infinity property?

Tags: javascript, infinity

I accidentally faced an [Infinity property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_infinity.asp) in JavaScript and wondered where in the world it can be used? Any real life example please.

Comment: Can think of only 1/0 == Infinity but that does no sense where it can be used.

Comment: It's the minimum value in an empty array of numbers

Comment: Cant agree that my question is too broad. I mentioned "Any real life example please."

Comment: I don't get why people downvote this, it seems as a legitemate question and it made me curious too. upvote

Comment: One possible usage example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12900504/1249581.

Comment: A cool use is `.flat(Infinity)` to deep flatten any array of arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're asking about why there's an `Infinity` global property, not why there's a concept of having infinities in the first place, which is another matter.

It allows easy comparison with the `Infinity` value itself, where you get it from some arithmetic:

```
function inv(x) {
  return x * 100000000000;
}

inv(1e999) === Infinity;
```

This is especially useful as `1 / 0` is not equal to `Infinity` in mathematics, so it's not obvious that you can use `1 / 0`.

If you want a numeric comparison to always return true, and you're using a variable, you can set the variable to Infinity to always force the condition to be true. Take this example:

```
var a = Infinity; // some number from elsewhere
var arr = [];
function foo(maxLen) {
  if (arr.length < maxLen) arr.push(1);
}

foo(a); // you can't change the function
```

This could be useful in cases where you can't change the comparison statement used.

Comment: Why do I need to that instead of just returning true?

Comment: @Vladimirs: `true` does not do the same thing, if the other side is `2` that's useless.

Comment: This does not make sense OneKitten. It would be equal to write `function foo(x) { alert(1); }` though I am not sure what `if(Infinity > Infinity)` would result in.

Comment: @StefanR.Falk: that was just meant to be an example, I thought that it was obvious that `a` wouldn't always be `Infinity` and would come from some external source.

Answer (score 4):

You can use it if you don't know what the minimum value of an `array` or also a `mathematical-function` is like this:

```
var minimum = Infinity;
var i = 0;

for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

   if(array[i] < minimum) {
     // new minimum found
     minimum = array[i];
   }
}

alert("Minimum: " + minimum);
```

Comment: `Math.min.apply` should be the choice.

Comment: This is just an example how `Infinity` can be and is used. What answer would that be: "*Use library function X*." ?

Comment: I asked about real life example I can write a whole bunch of code where I can put Infinity. Ideally I wanted to see example where I cant go without Infinity. Because for me it looks like just useless property.

Comment: The term *real life example* is kind of bad chosen. `Infinity` is useful in such cases I showed you and it also can be helpful as indicator for mathematical functions which produce figures which can not be stored in variables. In many cases e.g. `elliptic curve cryptography` you will make use of that property and I am sure there are many other examples out there like `ecc`. So what is your point anyway?

Comment: @Vladimirs see my edit. but you might want to read something about ECC yourself since I am not familiar with the mathematical background.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another real life example:

```
var x = +prompt('Enter x:'),
    y = +prompt('Enter y:'),
    value = Math.pow(x, y);

if (value === Infinity || value === -Infinity) {
    console.log('The value is too large!');
}
```

As an example, if the entered values are `1e100` and `100`, the power method returns `Infinity`.

Comment: Number.isFinite() is better to use there, but seems it just a shortcut to your condition

Comment: @Vladimirs Yeah, but if you need to separate the positive and negative conditions `isFinite` won't really work. Moreover, calling a method in the condition is always slower than checking against the value.