# How to write the maxint without using the library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I am not sure what `maxint` is, and what it does. But I am trying to solve this problem without using `maxint`, possibly write another function to do this.

I would like to write this function without using:

`from sys import maxint`

Here is what I am trying to implement without using `maxint`.

```
def maxSubArraySum(a,size):

    maxi = -maxint - 1
    maxi_ends = 0

    for i in range(0, size):
        maxi_ends = maxi_ends + a[i]
        if (maxi < maxi_ends):
            maxi = maxi_ends

        if maxi_ends < 0:
            maxi_ends = 0
    return maxi
```

Comment: This is someone not understanding how `int` objects work in Python. `maxint` is not appropriate here, since I can easily create smaller/ bigger integers. An appropriate value would be something like `maxi = float('-inf')`.

Comment: `sys.maxint` was [removed in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#integers). You might be able to use `sys.maxsize` instead — although it's unclear whether you understand the meaning of either of these constants.

Comment: This code is unclear.  Why do you create the variable `max_ending_here` and then never use it?  What is the purpose of the `maxi_ends` variable, when it is guaranteed to always be zero?

Comment: There's no limit to the size of integers in Python (other than how much memory is available), so `maxint` is meaningless. This may be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to calculate in your function?

Answer (score 0):

this is a common pattern in programming (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23407095/7006570)): to find the maximum number in a list, initialize `ans` to a value that's guaranteed to be lower than anything else in the list, then go through the list and simply perform the operation

```
if element > ans:
    ans = element
```

alternatively, you could set `ans` to be the value of the first value, but this is less elegant, since you need to check for the existence of the first element (otherwise, if the list is empty, you will get an error).  Or, the "list" might not be an actual list, but rather an iterator, like in your example, so getting the first value would be messy.

Anyways, that's the point of initializing your variable to be an extreme value.  MaxInt, in other languages like java and C, are very useful and nice to use as this extreme value, because the values you encounter along the way are literally not possibly bigger than MaxInt.

But note that, as I said in the very beginning, the point of infinity/maxint/minint is only to be larger/smaller than anything you could possibly encounter.  So, for problems like the one you posted, you can usually easily make yourself a lower-bound for the smallest possible value of any `maxi_ends`.  And you can make it a really loose lower-bound too (it doesn't have to be realistically attainable).  So here, one way to find the lowest possible value of `maxi_ends` would be the sum of all the negative values in `a`.  `maxi_ends` can't possibly go any lower than that.

Even easier, if you know what the smallest possible value of `a[i]` is, and you know the maximum possible length of `a`, you can calculate the smallest possible value that `maxi_end` could take for any input, right off the bat.  This is useful in these kinds of abstract programming problems that you see on coding competitions, coding interview prep, and homework, especially since you just need a quick and dirty solution.  For example, if `a[i]` can't be any less than `-100`, and `len(a)` is at most 1000, then `maxi_end` will never exceed `-100 * 1000 = -100000`, so you can just write `maxi = -100001`.

It's also a useful python trick in some real life situations (again, where you only need a quick hack) to pick a preposterously large number if you are lazy -- for example, if you're estimating the shortest path, in miles, between two buildings in a road network -- you could just pick 1000000000000 as an upper-bound, since you know no path will ever be that high.

I don't know why you don't want to use `sys.maxint` (although as the comments say, it's a good idea not to use it), but there are actual ways to [represent infinity in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781260/how-can-i-represent-an-infinite-number-in-python): in python 3.5 or above, you can do

```
import math
test = math.inf
```

and otherwise, you can use `float('inf')`.