# Correct HTML upload accept attribute for audio/viso

Tags: html, file-upload

I would like the same input to accept audio/video/image files only.

What is the correct accept attribute value for this?

For images I only need to support gif/jpeg/jpg/png.

currently I am testing this:

```
accept="image/video/audio/png/gif/jpeg/jpg/mp3/mp4,video/x-m4v,video/*"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify additional MIME types and/or extensions if you need:

```
accept="video/*,audio/*,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/png,.gif,.jpeg,.jpg,.png"
```

Documentation: [File Upload state (`type=file`)](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#file-upload-state-%28type=file%29)

Answer (score 0):

[***Demo Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/tZbeC/)

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var validExtensions = ["jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png", "mp3", "mp4"];
    var files = evt.target.files[0];
    var ext = files.name.split('.').pop();
    if (validExtensions.indexOf(ext) > -1) {
        alert("Valid");
    } else {
        alert("Invalid");
    }
}
document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

**This method is based on comparing the *`extension of the uploaded file`* with the array of valid extensions. So user can easily *`validate`* this by changing the extension of the file.**
 For ex. Renaming the `image.bmp` to `image.jpg`

Reference:
1. [For File Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/190878/2260614)