# Validate input to only accept one type of file extension

Tags: jquery, parsley.js

Does anyone know how can  I validate a file input to only accept `.zip` files with parsley.js?

I have looked around but I can not see how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a custom validator that validates the extension of the provided file path and check if it's `zip`. Something like this (check [**this jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/qabc0bwq/)):

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="file" name="some-file" data-parsley-fileextension='zip' />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.ParsleyValidator
        .addValidator('fileextension', function (value, requirement) {
            // the value contains the file path, so we can pop the extension
            var fileExtension = value.split('.').pop();

            return fileExtension === requirement;
        }, 32)
        .addMessage('en', 'fileextension', 'The extension doesn\'t match the required');

    $("#myForm").parsley();
});
</script>
```

Note that we set the attribute `data-parsley-fileextension='zip'` on the input in order to know which extension must be provided. On the custom validator (which I named `fileextension`) you have to take the extension from the file path and check if it matches the one you want.

You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1203361/908174) to find ways to get the extension from a file path in javascript.

If you need to validate multiple extensions, you just have to tweak this solution a bit.