# How to identify if a file is a javascript file or not?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing a program in `node.js`.

I want to create a function `isJsFile(file)` that get a `file (name or content)` and return true if the file is `javascript file` or `false` if its not.

**How can i create this function?**

Comment: May detect if it ends on .js?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190852/how-can-i-get-file-extensions-with-javascript

Comment: I can't trust the file extension,  i am working on files that i get from servers using http\s protocol , some of the files i get don't have ext, that is, the file doesn't ends with .js and the mime type isn't javascript. I need to find a way using only the file content to know if the file is javascript or not.

Comment: Solve the problem by using esPrima

Answer (score 0):

You can to use node-mime to indentity by mime type:
https://github.com/broofa/node-mime

Comment: I can't trust the file extension or mim type,  i am working on files that i get from servers using http\s protocol , some of the files i get don't have ext, that is, the file doesn't ends with .js and the mime type isn't javascript. I need to find a way using only the file content to know if the file is javascript or not.

Comment: you can use regular expression to determinate content )

Comment: i don't think that regular expression will help here, javascript is too complicate for this, unless you have an idea how?

Comment: If you can't trust to mime and file extension - you have two options: or regular expression or try to eval code

Comment: Perhaps using esprima will help here?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use file(1) utility that runs a number of tests against the file contents to classify it. Node.js has a module `file-type` that provides the functionality equivalent to file(1).

```js
import {fileTypeFromFile} from 'file-type';

console.log(await fileTypeFromFile('test.js'));
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply use path to get the file extension:

```
var path = require('path')
path.extname(YOUR_FILENAME) // returns '.js' if file is a js file
```

Comment: I can't trust the file extension or mim type,  i am working on files that i get from servers using http\s protocol , some of the files i get don't have ext, that is, the file doesn't ends with .js and the mime type isn't javascript. I need to find a way using only the file content to know if the file is javascript or not.