# regular expressions for files with no extension

Tags: regex

new to regex, is there a way to determine files having no extension?

Also need another one for .zip files

```
(//).test(files[i])
```

Comment: What is your regex language/tool?

Comment: I'm using javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to get extentions I've found is from: [How can I get file extensions with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190852/how-can-i-get-file-extensions-with-javascript).  This isn't regex, but you don't need regex - so unless this is a learning exercise, I'd go with string-based functions.

With that in hand you can check for blank as:

```
if(filename.substr((~-filename.lastIndexOf(".") >>> 0) + 2).length==0)
```

and for zips as:

```
if(filename.substr((~-filename.lastIndexOf(".") >>> 0) + 2)=="zip")
```

Check out that other post, if you definitely want regex - there are a couple good ones in there.