# Get file extension if operating system hide it

Tags: javascript

I have the html file input:

```
<input type='file' id='upload' accept='audio/*'  onchange='getFileType(this);return false;' />
```

And javascript function:

```
function getFileType(fl){
   var fileExt = "." + fl.value.match(/\.([^\.]+)$/)[1];
   alert(fileExt);
}
```

It works good, but if operating system is configured to hide known mime types so file extension is missing. And `fl.value.match(/\.([^\.]+)$/)[1]` is crushes on `null[1]` - "Cannot read property '1' of null".

So how I can get file extension on this case? I need cross browsers solution.

Comment: If the system is not giving you a file extension then you cannot get the file extension. Are you sure it does not? Can you console.log(fl) ?  Also if it DOES give the extension, then this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190852/how-can-i-get-file-extensions-with-javascript - -also look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299806/how-to-check-file-mime-type-with-javascript-before-upload

Comment: What OS are you referring to? Windows has a similar feature but it works at Explorer level, not file system level.

Comment: write now is happens on android version 5.1.1. With hidden mime types

Comment: why do you need the file extension? if you want the mimeType, don't trust your user. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299806/how-to-check-file-mime-type-with-javascript-before-upload