# ngSwitch not showing item when evaluated to true

Tags: angular, ng-switch

I'm not sure what I'm doing here. I have this ngSwitch inside ngFor

```html
          <li class="b-inBoxItem" *ngFor="let item of uploader.queue">
                <div [ngSwitch]="item.file.name">
                    <span *ngSwitchCase="item.file.name.includes('.png')" class="ic ic-file-image"></span>
                    <span *ngSwitchCase="item.file.name.includes('.jpeg')" class="ic ic-file-image"></span>
                    <span *ngSwitchCase="item.file.name.includes('.doc')" class="ic ic-file-stats"></span>
                        .
                        .
                        .
                    <span *ngSwitchDefault class="ic ic-file-empty"></span>
                </div>
          </li>
```

when I look in the debugger, I can see that the first case .png is being evaluated as true:

```html
<!--bindings={
    "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "true"
}-->
```

Rest of them are evaluated as false.

however, only the default item is being displayed.

What am I doing wrong here?

Tom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ngSwitch` directive is similar to the `switch` statement. It displays the element for which the `ngSwitchCase` value is equal to the `ngSwitch` variable. Here is an example taken from [this Rangle.io article](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/directives/ng_switch_directives.html):

```
<div [ngSwitch]="tab">
  <app-tab-content *ngSwitchCase="1">Tab content 1</app-tab-content>
  <app-tab-content *ngSwitchCase="2">Tab content 2</app-tab-content>
  <app-tab-content *ngSwitchCase="3">Tab content 3</app-tab-content>
  <app-tab-content *ngSwitchDefault>Select a tab</app-tab-content>
</div>
```

---

In your case, an expression gives a boolean value for each `ngSwitchCase`. You end up with the equivalent of:

```
<li class="b-inBoxItem" *ngFor="let item of uploader.queue">
  <div [ngSwitch]="item.file.name">
    <span *ngSwitchCase="true" class="ic ic-file-image"></span>
    <span *ngSwitchCase="false" class="ic ic-file-image"></span>
    <span *ngSwitchCase="false" class="ic ic-file-stats"></span>
      .
      .
      .
    <span *ngSwitchDefault class="ic ic-file-empty"></span>
  </div>
</li>
```

The default `span` is displayed because `item.file.name` is not equal to `true` or `false`.

---

To make it work, specify the file extension in `ngSwitch` and test the possible values:

```
<li class="b-inBoxItem" *ngFor="let item of uploader.queue">
  <div [ngSwitch]="getFileExtension(item.file.name)">
    <span *ngSwitchCase="'png'" class="ic ic-file-image"></span>
    <span *ngSwitchCase="'jpeg'" class="ic ic-file-image"></span>
    <span *ngSwitchCase="'doc'" class="ic ic-file-stats"></span>
      .
      .
      .
    <span *ngSwitchDefault class="ic ic-file-empty"></span>
  </div>
</li>
```

with the method (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/190852/1009922)):

```
getFileExtension(filename: string): string {
  return filename.split('.').pop();
}
```

---

An alternative solution is to use `ngIf`:

```
<li class="b-inBoxItem" *ngFor="let item of uploader.queue">
  <div>
    <span *ngIf="item.file.name.includes('.png')" class="ic ic-file-image"></span>
    <span *ngIf="item.file.name.includes('.jpeg')" class="ic ic-file-image"></span>
    <span *ngIf="item.file.name.includes('.doc')" class="ic ic-file-stats"></span>
      .
      .
      .
    <span *ngIf="!item.file.name.includes('.png') && !item.file.name.includes('.jpeg') && !item.file.name.includes('.doc')" class="ic ic-file-empty"></span>
  </div>
</li>
```