# unable to effectively find the file extension of a file among the given file extensions

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

here i need the find the file extension among the given file names i.e 
i have 2 variable  one is **fileData** which contains the file extensions and **filename** which contains the filename so here we have to check the whether the filenames having that particular extension or not if it is having then we have to retrieve the filename extension

```
fileData = ['exe', 'obj', 'file', 'data'];
filename = ['one.exe', 'two.obj', 'three.p', null, undefined];

constructor() {
  var fileSplit;
  for (var i of this.filename) {
    fileSplit = i.substring(i.lastIndexOf('.') + 1, i.length) || i;

    if (this.fileData.includes(fileSplit)) {

      console.log('File name::', i, 'and file extension::', fileSplit);
    } else {
      console.log('File name not there::', i)
    }
  }
}
```

**GETTING THIS ERROR : ERROR**

> Error: Cannot read property 'substring' of null

stackblitz link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ott3vh

Comment: Welcome! What is your expectation? sufficient or not means what? Can you write what you're expecting.

Comment: @Kaushik from fileData  im providing a set of file extensions and using the filename im providing a group of file name now im trying check whether the filename having the particular extension or not if extension are having then we have to retreive the extension

Comment: in the first line of for loop check whether the `i` is not equal to undefined or null. then proceed.

Comment: @Kaushik is my code my robust way to check like this ? or is there any best approach ?

Comment: You can go with this!

Answer (score 1):

You are doing the split without checking for undefined cases. Do this:

```
fileData =['exe','obj','file','data'];
filename =['one.exe','two.obj','three.p',null,undefined];

constructor(){
   var fileSplit = "";
   for(var i of this.filename){
        fileSplit = "";
        if(i){ 
            fileSplit = i.substring(i.lastIndexOf('.')+1, i.length) || i;
            if(this.fileData.includes(fileSplit)){
                console.log('File name::',i,'and file extension::',fileSplit);
            } else{
                 console.log('File name not there::',i);
            }
        } // Do all the above if(i)
   }
}
```

Comment: is my code my robust way to check like this ? or is there any best approach ?

Comment: Are you asking if your code is robust while performing the above task?

Comment: yes it fills my use case but still want to know is this the best approach

Comment: Using regex is another option, but will be a bit expensive. This solution is pretty good I assume. Please check this answer for handling filename extensions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1203361/6138595

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add [**short circuiting**](https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-is-short-circuit-evaluation-ff22b2f5608c?gi=4d59308a3a79) (`&&`) to check for true value and then use split

```js
let fileData =['exe','obj','file','data'];
let filename =['one.exe','two.obj','three.p',null,undefined, 'some.some.data'];

function checkFile(fileData,fileName){
   var fileSplit;
   for(var i of filename){
     fileSplit = i && i.split('.')
     fileSplit = fileSplit && fileSplit[fileSplit.length-1]
  
     if(i && fileData.includes(fileSplit)){

       console.log('File name::',i,'and file extension::',fileSplit);
     }else{
       console.log('File name not there::',i)
     }
   }
}
   
checkFile(fileData, filename)
```

Comment: can we ommit the result the null and undefined  ?

Comment: @phan686 okay, in that case just take the last element of splitted array

Comment: is my code my robust way to check like this ? or is there any best approach ?

Comment: @phan686 yeah it's fine, all you need is to check the value before using that can you apply `substring` method on it or not

Answer (score 0):

You have `null` and `undefined` in your fileName array. While iterating, you need to first check for `null` values and proceed only if it exists.

```
for(var i of this.filename){
   if (i == null || i==undefined){
      console.log('File name not there::',i)
   } else {
      fileSplit = i.substring(i.lastIndexOf('.')+1, i.length) || i;
      if(this.fileData.includes(fileSplit)){
         console.log('File name::',i,'and file extension::',fileSplit);
      } else {
         console.log('File extension not there::',i)
      }  
   }

}
```