# How to get suffix of filename in javascript quickly?

Tags: javascript

This question has been asked a couple of times here on SO, but most answers are simply slow. I need the fastest implementation possible since I execute this on million filenames in a list.

```
filename.split(".").pop();
```

The code above works but imagine a long filename, isn't there a way to start from the right? Otherwise, i could imagine that this here is faster than the common answers:

```
filename.reverse().split(".", 1).reverse()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `lastIndexOf` to iterate from the end of the string backwards to find the `.`, then slice the string:

```js
const filename = 'foo/bar/baz/my-file.js';
const extension = filename.slice(filename.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
console.log(extension);
```

Comment: Uh! That is even better!! Thanks! Answer accepted once I can

Answer (score 1):

You can also check that answer (and other answers in that question), it contains several methods with a benchmark: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12900504/4636502