# Check if file is an image or video, and use right tags?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

What’s the most efficient way to check if a file is an Img/video. And then upload the appropriate tag in react?

I’m not aware of an “does everything” tag in react…so would I have to use a if/else check and then use an image or video tag?

Note: could be muliptle versions of a image(jpg/png/webp)

Answer (score 0):

1-Use this link to get the extension of the file:
[How can I get file extensions with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190852/how-can-i-get-file-extensions-with-javascript/12900504#12900504)
2-define 2 states (imageFile and videoFile) and set the states to indicate whether you have an image or a video:

```
if (extension==="jpg" ||
      extention==="png"){
    setImageFile(true)
}
```

3- Do conditional rendering like below:

```
<div>
   {imageFile && <img>{file}</img>}
   {videoFile && <video>{file}</video>}
</div>
```