# Use just regexp to split a string into a 'tuple' of filename and extension?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, capturing-group

I know there are easier ways to [get file extensions with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190852/how-can-i-get-file-extensions-with-javascript), but partly to practice my regexp skills I wanted to try and use a regular expression to split a filename into two strings, before and after the final dot (`.` character).

Here's what I have so far

```js
const myRegex = /^((?:[^.]+(?:\.)*)+?)(\w+)?$/
const [filename1, extension1] = 'foo.baz.bing.bong'.match(myRegex);
// filename1 = 'foo.baz.bing.'
// extension1 = 'bong'
const [filename, extension] = 'one.two'.match(myRegex);
// filename2 = 'one.'
// extension2 = 'two'
const [filename, extension] = 'noextension'.match(myRegex);
// filename2 = 'noextension'
// extension2 = ''
```

I've tried to use negative lookahead to say 'only match a literal . if it's followed by a word that ends in, like so, by changing `(?:\.)*` to `(?:\.(?=\w+.))*`:

`/^((?:[^.]+(?:\.(?=(\w+\.))))*)(\w+)$/gm`

But I want to exclude that final period using just the regexp, and preferably have 'noextension' be matched in the initial group, how can I do that with just regexp?

Here is my regexp scratch file: https://regex101.com/r/RTPRNU/1

Comment: You can only match word characters using `^(\w+(?:\.\w+)*?)(?:\.(\w+))?$` having optional repetitions of `.` and word characters in a group. Seehttps://regex101.com/r/lMsjRj/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew because I had no thought of that

Comment: @Thefourthbird that would also be a perfectly valid answer

Comment: @Pureferret I posted an answer. You could wait for Wiktor to post his solution and accept that as he solved the problem first.

Comment: @Pureferret ... how about something more explicit and accurate without looking around ... [`/^(?<noextension>\w+)$|(?<filename>\w+(?:\.\w+)*)\.(?<extension>\w+)$/`](https://regex101.com/r/RTPRNU/3) or without named groups ... [`/^(\w+)$|(\w+(?:\.\w+)*)\.(\w+)$/`](https://regex101.com/r/RTPRNU/2)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You can post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first capture group, you could start the match with 1 or more word characters. Then optionally repeat a `.` and again 1 or more word characters.

Then you can use an optional non capture group matching a `.` and capturing 1 or more word characters in group 2.

As the second non capture group is optional, the first repetition should be on greedy.

```
^(\w+(?:\.\w+)*?)(?:\.(\w+))?$
```

The pattern matches

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\w+(?:\.\w+)*?` Match 1+ word characters, and optionally repeat `.` and 1+ word characters
- `)` Close group 1
- `(?:` Non capture group to match as a whole

  - `\.(\w+)` Match a `.` and capture 1+ word chars in capture **group 2**
- `)?` Close non capture group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lMsjRj/1)

```js
const regex = /^(\w+(?:\.\w+)*?)(?:\.(\w+))?$/;
[
  "foo.baz.bing.bong",
  "one.two",
  "noextension"
].forEach(s => {
  const m = s.match(regex);
  if (m) {
    console.log(m[1]);
    console.log(m[2]);
    console.log("----");
  }
});
```

Another option as @[Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew) posted in the comments, is to use a non greedy dot to match any character for the filename:

```
^(.*?)(?:\.(\w+))?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5Gjemb/1)

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to do a late pitch-in on this because I wanted to split up a filename into a "name" and an "extension" part - and wasn't able to find any good solutions supporting all my test cases ... and I wanted to support filenames starting with "." which should return as the "name" and I wanted to support files without any extension too.

So I'm using this line which handles all my use-cases

```
const [name, ext] = (filename.match(/(.+)+\.(.+)/) || ['', filename]).slice(1)
```

Which will give this output

```
'.htaccess' => ['.htaccess', undefined]
'foo' => ['foo', undefined]
'foo.png' => ['foo', 'png']
'foo.bar.png' => ['foo.bar', 'png']
'' => ['', undefined]
```

I find that to be what I want.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use regex, I would suggest to use two regex:

```js
// example with 'foo.baz.bing.bong'

const firstString = /^.+(?=\.\w+)./g // match 'foo.baz.bing.' 
const secondString = /\w+$/g   // match 'bong'
```

Comment: Can you make a full snippet which test your regex ?

Answer (score 0):

How about something more explicit and accurate without looking around ...

1. named groups variant ... [`/^(?<noextension>\w+)$|(?<filename>\w+(?:\.\w+)*)\.(?<extension>\w+)$/`](https://regex101.com/r/RTPRNU/3)
2. without named groups ... [`/^(\w+)$|(\w+(?:\.\w+)*)\.(\w+)$/`](https://regex101.com/r/RTPRNU/2)

Both of the just shown variants can be shortened to 2 capture groups instead of the above variant's 3 capture groups, which in my opinion makes the regex easier to work with at the cost of being less readable ...

3. named groups variant ... [`/(?<filename>\w+(?:\.\w+)*?)(?:\.(?<extension>\w+))?$/`](https://regex101.com/r/RTPRNU/5)
4. without named groups ... [`/(\w+(?:\.\w+)*?)(?:\.(\w+))?$/`](https://regex101.com/r/RTPRNU/4)

```js
const testData = [
  'foo.baz.bing.bong',
  'one.two',
  'noextension',
];
// https://regex101.com/r/RTPRNU/5
const regXTwoNamedFileNameCaptures = /(?<filename>\w+(?:\.\w+)*?)(?:\.(?<extension>\w+))?$/;
// https://regex101.com/r/RTPRNU/4
const regXTwoFileNameCaptures = /(\w+(?:\.\w+)*?)(?:\.(\w+))?$/;

// https://regex101.com/r/RTPRNU/3
const regXThreeNamedFileNameCaptures = /^(?<noextension>\w+)$|(?<filename>\w+(?:\.\w+)*)\.(?<extension>\w+)$/
// https://regex101.com/r/RTPRNU/3
const regXThreeFileNameCaptures = /^(\w+)$|(\w+(?:\.\w+)*)\.(\w+)$/

console.log(
  'based on 2 named file name captures ...\n',
  testData, ' =>',
  testData.map(str =>
    regXTwoNamedFileNameCaptures.exec(str)?.groups ?? {}
  )
);
console.log(
  'based on 2 unnamed file name captures ...\n',
  testData, ' =>',
  testData.map(str => {
    const [
      match,
      filename,
      extension,
    ] = str.match(regXTwoFileNameCaptures) ?? [];
  //] = regXTwoFileNameCaptures.exec(str) ?? [];

    return {
      filename,
      extension,
    }
  })
);

console.log(
  'based on 3 named file name captures ...\n',
  testData, ' =>',
  testData.map(str => {
    const {
      filename = '',
      extension = '',
      noextension = '',
    } = regXThreeNamedFileNameCaptures.exec(str)?.groups ?? {};

    return {
      filename: filename || noextension,
      extension,
    }
  })
);
console.log(
  'based on 3 unnamed file name captures ...\n',
  testData, ' =>',
  testData.map(str => {
    const [
      match,
      noextension = '',
      filename = '',
      extension = '',
    ] = str.match(regXThreeFileNameCaptures) ?? [];
  //] = regXThreeFileNameCaptures.exec(str) ?? [];

    return {
      filename: filename || noextension,
      extension,
    }
  })
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```