# How can I check the number of files in a local folder by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, frontend

need to get the number of images in folder from directory just by javascript.

I searched and tried several ways, but i didn't find any javascript solution.

Comment: You can't, JS can't access local file system.

Answer (score 0):

Using frontend JS is not possible, but using NodeJS it is.

In case you want to achieve it using NodeJS, I wrote an example of reading and retrieving the count of 'png' files in a directory. This is how I achieved it:

1-Build a NodeJS project:

```bash
mkdir myProject
cd myProject
npm init -y
```

2-Write the example:

```
touch index.js
```

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const dir = '.'
const fileExtension = 'png'

fs.readdir(dir, (err, files) => {
  let count = 0

  files.forEach(element => {
    if (getFileExtension(element) === fileExtension) {
      count++
    }
  })

  console.log(count)
})

/**
 * 
 * @param {String} fileName 
 * @source https://stackoverflow.com/a/12900504
 * @returns 
 */
const getFileExtension = fileName => {
  return fileName.slice((fileName.lastIndexOf(".") - 1 >>> 0) + 2)
}
```

3-Execute it:

```bash
node index.js

2 //  <- output
```

Comment: The `fs` module is already part of Node. Why would you run `npm i fs`?

Comment: you are right, let me fix it